# jQuery - Adding list-item element if there is less than three

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I need to do is make sure that every unordered list has at least three list-item elements inside of it. So how can I loop through the ul elements and make sure there is at least three li children inside.

And if there is only one li I need it to a two more. If there is two li's I need to add just one more.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>
```

The reason I need to do this is that the info is being fed in through a WordPress loop and if it doesn't loop in at least three elements of content I need to add more empty ones till it reaches at least 3.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a variable that holds the max of `li`'s you want every `ul` to contain, then compare the number of the `li`'s you've in every single `ul` with it (`max_lis` variable) to know how more additional `li`'s you've to add, and finally loop and add them to the current `ul` using `append`.

Hope this helps.

```js
var max_lis = 3;

$('ul.list').each(function(){
  var lis_length = $('li',this).length;

  if( lis_length )
      additional_lis = max_lis - lis_length;
  else
      additional_lis = max_lis;
  
   for(i=0;i<additional_lis;i++)
      $(this).append('<li style="color:red;">... NEW content</li>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `for` loop that starts from current number of `li`'s in ul.

```js
$('ul').each(function() {
  var i = $(this).find("li").length;
  for (i; i < 3; i++) $(this).append('<li>New item</li>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```js
var lists = $('ul');
for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    var items = $('li', lists[i]);
    if(items.length < 3) {
        console.log(lists[i].id+ ' - add more list');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list" id="list1">
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list" id="list2">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list" id="list3">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list" id="list4">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` to filter `ul` elements having less than `3` `li` elements, create an array having `3` minus `.length` of `li` child elements within selected `ul`, `.append()` array of elements to `ul`.

```js
$("ul")
.filter(function(i, el) {
  return $("li", this).length < 3
})
.each(function(i, el) {
  $(this).append(Array(3 - $("li", el).length).fill("<li>...content</li>"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
  <li>...content</li>
</ul>
```